# Pandas find delta between DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the difference between two Pandas DateTimeIndex datasets.

```
start_date = "2012-01-01"
end_date = "2012-12-31"

workdays = pd.bdate_range(start_date,end_date)
all_days = pd.date_range(start_date,end_date)
```

I have tried:

```
#Method A
weekends = np.subtract(all_days, workdays)
#ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (366,) (262,) 

#Method B
weekends = pd.DatetimeIndex
for d in all_days:
    if d not in workdays:
        weekends.append(d)
#TypeError: append() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

#Method C
weekends = all_days - workdays.reindex(all_days.index, fill_value=0)
#AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'index'

#Method D
weekends = all_days - workdays
#ValueError: cannot add indices of unequal length
```

Pandas version == 0.23.4

Any idea how I can do this

Comment: How do you expect to subtract two arrays of unequal lengths?  What is `[4,5,6] - [1,2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this to get the weekends:

```
import numpy as np

weekends = all_days[np.logical_not(all_days.isin(workdays))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to get all the weekend dates, this is much more efficient and direct:

```
satsun = pd.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(weekmask='Sat Sun')
offdays = pd.bdate_range(start_date, end_date, weekmask=satsun)
```

See the docs on `weekmask` here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.busdaycalendar.html